# How to simulate pressing enter in html text input with Selenium?

Tags: user-interface, selenium, selenium-rc

In a web interface, I've got a text field. When user enters text and accepts with enter, application performs an action.

I wanted to test the behavior with Selenium. Unfortunately, invoking 'keypress' with chr(13) insert representation of the character into the field.

Is there a way other then submitting the form? I'd like to mimic intended user interaction, without any shortcuts...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This Java code works for me:

```
selenium.keyDown(id, "\\13");
```

Notice the escape. You probably need something like chr(\13)

Comment: what about situation when i got error message and there isn't any id about that button? Can i somehow just press enter by selenium?

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using selenium.keyPress(id, "\\13");

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tested this I imagine you can use "\r\n" appended to a string to simulate a new line. If not look for the languages equivalent to "Environment.NewLine;" ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've had to do this, but I seem to recall having to use a javascript snippet to execute the carrage return as opposed to using the Selenium keypress  function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
Webelement.sendkeys(Keys.Enter);